# Using a sans serif text font with XITS math

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, stix

I'm working with a Macintosh and am looking for a clear, readable sans serif font which would be vaguely compatible with XITS Math.  I've tried Helvetica Sans, but am finding the the x-height to ascender height ratio is sufficiently different from that of XITS Math that it looks quite ugly.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please see the guide to learn about the site format as this question seems opinion-based and/or unclear. You can scale one font to match another. See the `fontspec` manual for details. (I don't know what Helvetica Sans is. Do you not mean Helvetica?)

Comment: Thanks for replies!  Duh, I meant Helvetica Neue.  The issue is that Helvetica Neue's ascender height (the height of a letter "h", for example) divided by the x-height (the height of a letter "x") is approximately 1.36, whereas for XITS Math, it is roughly 1.50.  So if I scale the math font to have the same font size as the Helvetica, the x-height is significantly smaller, so something like "Let $x$ be..." has an x which is too short, whereas if I scale the math to have the same x-height, the numbers are too tall in "if $3x=5$ then...".  So a font with a ratio of about 1.50 would be great! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about choosing a font with a particular cap-height to x-height ratio, not about how to use said font in (La)TeX.